# How do I install BoofCV inside eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, computer-vision, boofcv

In a way that the entire library be inside a new project. I've searched and I found a video in youtube that explains, but in this manner, it opens several projects on eclipse and it's a chaos. I'm working in widows.I wanted to be the same way as JBox2D, but I don't know how to install BoofCV.
[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 2):

You can make a **User Library**.
**Step #1**. You may download the latest Compiled JARs, Source JARs and Dependencies from [here](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Download). Unzip all JAR files into a known folder with full permissions.
**Step #2**. Open Eclipse IDE and go to **Window=>Preferences=>User Libraries** and click on "New". Apply a name for your BoofCV library (like "BoofCV v0.26").
[image]
**Step #3**. Click on **Add External JARs...**, select from the folder you have stored all BoofCV JAR library files (or pick a specific one if you wish) and click **Open** and then **OK**.

**Step #4**. Almost done! Now you have to import those BoofCV libraries to your project. Click on menu **Project=>Properties=>Java Build Path=>Libraries(third tab on the right side)** and click **Add Library...**, select "**User Library**" and click next, then check your BoofCV library and click **Finish**. If you wish you may add this library to **Import and Export** list at the last tab.
**Step #5**. Now you click **OK** and enjoy BoofCV with Eclipse IDE!!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at switching your project over to Gradle or Maven.  It makes dependency management much easier.  All of that could be replaced with a single.

For example in Gradle:

```
compile 'org.boofcv:all:0.26'
```

There are Eclipse plugins for Gradle and Maven, but I haven't used them in a bit.